# Migrating VB6 with Quickbooks SDK to Intuit Partner Platform

Tags: vb6, migration, intuit-partner-platform

I have a VB6 desktop program that is using the Quickbooks SDK. I was trying to see if its possible to migrate it to the Quickbooks IPP system. Ive been looking through the Intuit IPP site for hours and i can't seem to make heads and tails of it. Is it even posible to connect the 2? is there any documentation on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can write the code to call REST APIs then you can access the APIs to integrate with Quickbooks on the Intuit Partner Platform. Its not limited by your programming language of choice.

There is no documentation about vb6, only on the details for the REST API you can call.
Here is the documentation for QuickBooks for Windows and QuickBooks Online APIs.

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services

You can also find the IPP QuickBooks SDKs for .Net here if you are interested in that route, it will save you time as you wont need to write alot of the code to handle the XML or make the http request calls.

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform

regards,
Jarred

Comment: From looking at the information it seems like the information is for websites aka javascript/asp.net not desktop applications, do you have to have a website as a medium to interface with the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

**What you're trying to do isn't possible right now.**

If you refer to the Intuit Anywhere [FAQs](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0080_FAQ) you'll see this relevant question:

> Q: What are the requirements for implementing Intuit Anywhere?
>
> A: Your app must:
>
> - Be a web app available for use within a browser, that is sold as service (SaaS, including transactional pricing based) offering that
>     you sell to multiple customers. Mobile extensions to your SaaS app are
>     supported.
> - Pass the Security Review prior to going live with customers.

And this relevant question:

> Q: Can I connect desktop apps with Intuit Anywhere?
>
> A: Not today, but we are considering it.

Thus, porting a desktop app isn't supported right now (unless, of course, you converted your *entire* application to be a web-based app...)